How to create and export a CSV file with data obtained from the database using Node.js and Express only?
How to create ad export a CSV file with data obtained from the database and will be triggered by the node-cron at a specific time and will upload the exported CSV file to the S3 bucket(without using frontend). WHAT WOULD BE THE PROCESS? Is it possible if there will be no endpoint?
I expect to export and generate CSV file that contains the retrieved data from the database that will be triggered by the cron.

What have you tried so far?
